# no color in .cu file in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda

I'm developing simple CUDA app. I followed steps given on http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2010/10/visual-studio-2010-adding-intellisense-support-for-cuda-c/ but still there is no color in .cu file. I mean everything is simply in black color what could be the reason?
I'm able to run program.

Comment: When I install Nsight for Visual Studio 2010, I get syntax highlighting in .cu files without any additional steps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: add the cu extension]

This image says it all.  Go to Tools > Options, then select Text Editor in the left column.  Then click on File Extension as shown.  Type cu under extension, pick Microsoft Visual C++ as the editor, and then hit Add.  In my experience, this is all that was necessary to make Visual Studio interpret/color my .cu files with c++ syntax.

Also note that this is similar to what the link you posted suggests.  This method is simply a visual description of that.  Also note that I didn't really do the extra steps listed on that website either because having **shared** and **device** and all colored didn't seem that important.

Hope that helps.