# How do I enable syntax highlighting of CUDA .cu files in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, cuda, editor

When I edit a `.cu` file in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, the editor treats it as a regular text file (there are no colors on keywords such as `int`, `float` etc. Closing brackets are not highlighted).

How do I enable syntax highlighting of `.cu` files in Visual Studio, so that editing `.cu` files is like editing regular C / C++ files?

Comment: Already answered in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090843/no-color-in-cu-file-in-vs-2010

Answer (score 21):

Adding '.cu' under c++ extension in visual studio settings would enable syntax highlighting for c++ keywords only. EDIT: It in `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> File Extension` type in cu and select Microsoft Visual C++ as the editor and click add

To add CUDA keyword syntax highlighting you can search for `usertype.dat` in your CUDA installation folders (make sure if it is not found in the Program Files folder to search for it in your `home folder -> AppData-> Local -> NVIDIA Corporation` (sorry that I'm not providing the details since I don't have Windows right now), then copy it to `Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE` and restart Visual Studio

But, But! still it might not work, so what you are ended up with AFAIK you can use Visual Assistant x and then you have to change it's settings as follows:

For VS2010, VS2008, VS2005 and VS.NET:

Add your extension to:

`Tools | Options | Projects | VC++ Build | C/C++ File Extensions (VS.NET)`

`Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | VC++ Project Settings | C/C++ File Extensions (VS2005, VS2008)`

`Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | VC++ Project Settings | Extensions To Include (VS2010)`

Exit the IDE and use regedit to clone the following entry to a like entry that ends in your extension:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\Languages\File Extensions\.cpp`

If you are using a 64bit OS then clone the registry key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\Languages\File Extensions\.cpp`

If your extension denotes a header, use `regedit` to add the extension to `ExtHeader` in the following location. Remember to include the dot and terminating semicolon:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Whole Tomato\Visual Assist X\VANet8`

If your extension denotes a source file that is not a header, add the extension to `ExtSource` in the following location.

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Whole Tomato\Visual Assist X\VANet8`

Press Rebuild on the Performance tab of the Visual Assist X options dialog and restart your IDE.

Replace `8.0` with `10.0` if you use VS 2010.
Replace `8.0` with `9.0` if you use VS 2008.
Replace `8.0` with `7.1` if you use VS.NET 2003.
Replace `8.0` with `7.0` if you use VS.NET 2002.

Replace `VANet8` with `VANet10` for Visual Studio 2010.
Replace `VANet8` with `VSNet9` if you use VS2008.
Replace `VANet8` with `VSNet` if you use VS.NET 2003.
Replace `VANet8` with `VANet7`.0 if you use VS.NET 2002.

For VC++ 6.0:

Exit your IDE and use `regedit` to add the extension to:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\DevStudio\6.0\Text Editor\Tabs/Language Settings\C/C++\FileExtensions`.

If your extension denotes a header, use `regedit` to add the extension to `ExtHeader` in the following location. Remember to include the dot and terminating semicolon:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Whole Tomato\Visual Assist X\VA6`

If your extension denotes a source file that is not a header, add the extension to `ExtSource` in the following location.Remember to include the dot and terminating semicolon:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Whole Tomato\Visual Assist X\VA6`

Press Rebuild on the Performance tab of the Visual Assist X options dialog and restart your IDE.

Comment: Should I be worried if I find the usertype.dat neither in my CUDA installation folders nor my NVIDIA Corporation folders? Furhtermore - what do I do now?

Comment: @Nummer_42O This is a very old workaround for VS 2010. Things might have changed since. I would post a new question with all the appropriate information so someone else can answer it with newer instrcutions.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to what someone else has already said (adding cu extension in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> File Extension and Microsoft Visual C++ as editor), I also recommend you, in order to avoid the highlighting of CUDA keywords (like threadIdx.x etc), to include:

```
#include<device_launch_parameters.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

Right click your project, select Build Customizations, then select one of the CUDA build customization files. If there are no CUDA build customization files available, you must first install Nsight Visual Studio Edition or a CUDA distribution in which it is bundled.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
```

In my VS I added these 2 lines and all the syntax highlighting were present afterwards.

Comment: I do not know what magic is behind these two headers, previously I had used only `#include "device_launch_parameters.h"` that highlighted some code snippets, and with `#include "cuda_runtime.h"` it even generates better syntax highlighter. However, the complete highlighting is still missing, there should be a second option.